# React, как правильно обновлять на проде, чтобы не удалять каждый раз кэш и куки?

Tags: reactjs, nginx

Приложение стоит на сервере **nginx**, когда делаю сборку серверве `npm run build`, то не обновляется на сайте информация, а остается старая, только после удаления куки и кэша всё обновляется.

Как правильно обновлять приложение, чтобы пользователь зашел и сразу видел обновлённое приложение?

Comment: Для этого добавляют хеш в имя bandle, это webpack делает из коробки.